# $L^2$ norm of inverse differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, inverse-problems

This has come up in Lemma 1 of Mandache's 2001 [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0ba3/9473bc3b9453994c659a9820aa76a38fed65.pdf) on exponential instability for the inverse problem of the Schrodinger operator. Let $\Omega = B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose $r_0\in (0,1)$ and $q$ is a function in $L^{\infty}$ supported on $B(0,r_0)$. Suppose also that $0$ is not a Dirichlet eigenvalue of $-\Delta+ q$, so that the boundary value problem $(-\Delta + q)u = F$ in $\Omega$,
$u = f$ on  $\partial\Omega$ has a unique solution $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ for any $F\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$, $f\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$.

I have two questions:

1. In the paper, the author uses the notation $(-\Delta + q)^{-1}$, which I would assume the operator that takes some $F\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ and maps it to the unique $u\in H^1$ such that $(-\Delta + f)u = F$; is this correct?
2. He also uses the norm $||(-\Delta + q)^{-1}||_{L^2}$; how am I to interpret this?

Comment: But $-\Delta + q$ here is not a function in $L^2$, but an operator from $H^{1/2}$ to $H^1$.

Comment: It seems it is the operator norm as an operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$

Comment: I think you're right, that seems to make the most sense and agrees with the computation in which this is used. Thanks!

Comment: Since then you get
$$
\|(\Delta +q)^{-1} (qu_0)\|_{L^2} ≤ \|(\Delta +q)^{-1}\|_{L^2\to L^2}\|  qu_0\|_{L^2} ≤ \|(\Delta +q)^{-1}\|_{L^2\to L^2}\| q\|_{L^\infty}\| u_0\|_{L^2}
$$